# How do I add a user to an FAQ Plus Chat Bot as an agent in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have 2 bots, one for the end-user which is installed in the end-users Microsoft Teams application and another bot for the experts which is installed in a channel under a team in Microsoft Teams.

When the end-user sends an Ask An Expert command from the end-user bot, the teams channel where the expert bot is installed will receive a card saying that someone is requesting support. So a user (mostly an agent) will be assigned to help this end-user.

Once the agent is assigned, the agent should be added to the end-user bot.

How do I do this?
[Add Agent to Bot Screen Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW2aw.png)

I tried using Direct Line API.

I created a class called AgentHandler which has a method called AddUserAsAgentAsync() which takes in two arguments, botId and userId of the user that has to be added to the bot.

Below is the code:

```csharp
public class AgentHandler
{
    private readonly string _accessToken;

    public AgentHandler()
    {
        _accessToken = "eyJhb**";
    }

    public async Task AddUserAsAgentAsync(string botId, string userId)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);

        var data = new { id = userId, role = "user" };
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{botId}/participants", content);
    }
}
```

I then call this method during OnMessageActivitySync() in the class which extends TeamsActivity Handler.

I am not able to add the user to the bot. It gives 404 in the response of the AddUserAsAgentAsync()

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at any of the "handoff" documentation and samples? See here as a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: I tried that, but I want to use FAQ Plus bot as the bot.

Comment: I'm not following your concern? FAQ Plus is just an app template, so you have access to the full code. You just need to modify it to add the Handoff features per the article I linked, based on whatever trigger you want to initiate the handoff (e.g. when the user says "Transfer to Agent" or something like that).

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand I can do that, but I would like to know if Microsoft Teams or the Bot Framework allows a user to be added to a FAQ Plus bot?

Comment: ok, I got you now, I thought handoff would be sufficient but I've re-read the question now. I've not tested this, but I think what could be happening, based on the screenshot, is that the chat is being converted from a 1-1 chat to a group chat. Basically, the "agent" user is being added to the chat. For that, this would probably do the trick: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http